# Imprimir informações de um arquivo php que gera json

Tags: php, mysql, json

[image: Imagem do que é impresso ao entrar na tela]

Meu arquivo dados.php gera um json na tela com os dados do banco, como eu poderia fazer para pegar esses dados json gerados e os imprimir em uma table por exemplo?

Comment: Pode seu código e explique melhor sua dúvida.

Comment: Você nem precisa converter para JSON, pode simplesmente percorrer o *array* e imprimir os valores.

Answer (score 0):

Muito simples. Pode usar: **file_get_contents** *(ou CURL)*, **json_decode** e um **foreach**.

Por exemplo, ficaria assim:

```
<?php

$json = file_get_contents("dados.json");
$dados = json_decode($json, TRUE);

echo "<table>";
echo "<tbody>";

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>ID</td>";
echo "<td>Empresa</td>";
echo "<td>Valor</td>";
echo "</tr>";

foreach ($dados as $info) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $info["id"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $info["empresa"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $info["valor"] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>"; 

?>
```

Você pode alterar no script o **dados.json** pela URL que você informou ou criar um script para salvá-lo e usá-lo, como fiz no exemplo.